# Slick.js, slider sync with beforeChange

Tags: synchronization, slider, carousel, slick.js

I have a problem with setting slick carousel in mode with sync navigation, to work like this:

**First transition**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L190U.jpg

**Second transition**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTu8l.jpg

**Third transition**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKU7W.jpg

The way I am doing it now, does not working as it should.

```
    $main_topic_slider.on('beforeChange', function(currentSlide){
        $main_topic_nav.slick('slickGoTo', currentSlide + 1);

    console.log('SLIDER:'+$main_topic_slider.slick('slickCurrentSlide'));
    console.log('NAV:'+$main_topic_nav.slick('slickCurrentSlide'));
    });
```

Slides behaviour not as they supposed:

SLIDER:0
NAV:1

SLIDER:0
NAV:1

SLIDER:1
NAV:2

SLIDER:0
NAV:1

SLIDER:1
NAV:2

Here is the way I initialize:

```
    var settings_main_topic = {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        fade: false,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 8000,
        asNavFor: $main_topic_nav,
        cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(.25,.46,.45,.94)',
        speed: 1000,
        initialSlide: 0
    },

    settings_main_topic_nav = {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        focusOnSelect: false,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 8000,
        asNavFor: $main_topic_slider,
        cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(.25,.46,.45,.94)',
        speed: 1000,
        initialSlide: 1
    }
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: I don't understand issue. Do you have issue in syncing slick slider?

Comment: No. I am trying to change the way sync slider shows slides in navigation. I do not want to take a place for the current slide in navigation slider (I got there 2 slides to show, so half of the nav took current slide - i do not need it). Navigation should always show just next slides and current in main slider. 

This is what picutres says about :)

Please help me!! :)

Comment: [link]https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/3150[/link]