# Filter slides in slick carousel not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow, slick.js

I am using SlickSlider with navigation, and I would like to hide there current slide, so I could show in navigation only those that are next.

I am was trying to do it like below, with use filter na beforeChange, but it does not work, and slick behave unexpectable.

```
    $main_topic_nav.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    $main_topic_nav.slick('slickFilter', $('.slick-slide:not([data-slick-index="'+ nextSlide +'"])'));
    });
```

Please help :))

Comment: I haven't worked with slick filter but I found this as reference. https://codepen.io/CAYdenberg/pen/ZGqbzw  By seeing this reference I suggest you to try fliter like this - `$main_topic_nav.slick('slickFilter', ':not([data-slick-index="'+ nextSlide +'"])');` and add this after initialization of slick slider instead of adding this in callback every time before slide changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I knew this codepen, and unfortunately it's still not the answer for my question :(

Comment: I had describe my issue more deeply in this post [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46543329/slick-js-slider-sync-with-beforechange[/link], there you can see pictures presenting behaviour I would like.